# "Another category are/is appearance-based methods"

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

> Another category of vision-based methods for fall detection **are**
>   appearance-based methods, which can be applied even with a single
>   camera, but can also benefit from multiple cameras so that they cover
>   larger areas.

In the above sentence, is it wrong to use *are*?

Comment: It's not "fall detection are", it's "vision-based methods are", where the subject and verb agree (unless it's "another category are", where the subject and verb disagree again).

Comment: I assume that "another category is appearance-based methods".

Comment: so my actual question is that is "are" for category or methods. Why is it for methods?

Comment: Yeah, but you shouldn't hafta assume anything. It's just badly written, is all.

Comment: It really should be **is**, but the nested prepositional phrases make it easy to get confused, even for native speakers.

Answer (score 0):

Summarising the comments: yes, *are* here should be *is*. Not, though, because of "for fall detection are" (which is irrelevant), but because of "Another category...are..."  The author's syntax is so contorted he has even confused himself.